# Groovy how can I build a custom library and use it in a project as dependency

Tags: groovy

I have a set of code procedures I use in a lot of places and I'm trying to basically move it to a library.

So I created my library with some unit test and everything was looking promising and at least working localy..

When I went to my project and deleted the files locally and then try to import them from my library as a dependency the code does not work.

I always get this kind of error

```
Class does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract getProperty(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
```

I'm definitely not an expert on groovy but basically I use it in my Jenkins and Gradle for pipelines and some basic packaging or environment deployments.

I can show my class:

```
class ConsoleRow implements Comparable {

...
    final Integer priority
    final String rowStatus
    final String message
    final String rowReportClass

    ConsoleRow(Integer priority, String status, String msg, String rowC) {
        this.priority = priority
        this.rowStatus = status
        this.message = msg
        this.rowReportClass = rowC
    }

    @Override
    int compareTo(Object o) {
        return this.priority <=> ((ConsoleRow) o).priority
    }
```

The line that gives me the error is this actual compareTo when trying to do the "this.priority"

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.abc.insight.jenkins.ConsoleRow does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract getProperty(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
        at com.abc.insight.jenkins.ConsoleRow.compareTo(ConsoleRow.groovy:24)
        at com.abc.insight.jenkins.ConsoleOutputHtmlBuilder.processOutput(ConsoleOutputHtmlBuilder.groovy:115)
        at com.abc.insight.jenkins.ConsoleOutputHtmlBuilder.processOutput(ConsoleOutputHtmlBuilder.groovy)
        at com.abc.insight.jenkins.ConsoleOutputHtmlBuilder.buildReport(ConsoleOutputHtmlBuilder.groovy:20)
        at com.abc.insight.jenkins.ConsoleOutputHtmlBuilder$buildReport.call(Unknown Source)
        at build_e548mc0tqjmi822clitlsycdk.runReport(C:\dev\repo\insight\insight-health-check\data-foundation\smoke-test\build.gradle:77)
```

The calling function is just trying to sort a list of those objects

```
    List<ConsoleRow> outputRows = []
    ...  
    return outputRows.sort()
```

The part that gets me really confused is that if instead of importing the library as a dependency I just do this directly in this repo and put my sources in my buildSrc\src\main\groovy\com\abc\insight the code works fine...
So I really think it might be how I package and publish my library that might be wrong.

I'm really sure this is some basic error on my part because I never did a groovy library before but somehow I can't make it work.

It might be that my publication is just wrong, on my library side I'm using this plugins to do the publishing.

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'base'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change components.groovy but somehow it does not work.

Any ideas or tips, I think my question probably is showing some really lack of know-how on groovy but looking at the documentation and examples I could not figure it out.

Doing some debug in my IDE the compareTo that generates the exception looks like this.

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();
    return ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareTo(this.priority, var2[0].callGroovyObjectGetProperty((ConsoleRow)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(o, ConsoleRow.class)));
}
```

I tried following this guide and code structure when doing moving the code to a library
https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_groovy_libraries.html

Thanks for any feedback

p.s: My code might look weird, I tried first to have everything with the def blablabla but I was having some issues with typecasting but I don't think this would be the reason for the problem I'm facing.

Anyway I got a look at the generated code in my IDE and I see a lot of get methods just no idea where they expected this getProperty from

Comment: I don't see in ConsoleRow class any dependency on any custom library class. I can't understand how custom library class placement could affect your code.

Comment: I'm a bit lost so maybe my question does not make any sense. my main point is this works fine until I moved it to a separate project and tried to build a library out of it. I'm not thinking that I'm using the wrong groovy version when compiling my code?
I tried to use groovy-all 3.0.9 because it was the latest but when I start the project with gradle init it goes to 2.5.11 so maybe I will try to downgrade to that

Comment: Align the versions of java and groovy to Jenkins. Also you could try to extend groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.. btw, ConsoleRow is it a part of library or Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: this was indeed the problem. All those classes were on the library, from the build.gradle I was just calling my library by initializing and calling the methods

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was definitely a user error.
I am using distribution version of gradle 6.5.1
When I did the gradle init to bootstrap my project I was provided with the dependency of gradle groovy-all version 2.5.11

```
implementation group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.5.11'
```

I thought that was a mistake and just updated to the latest version.

```
implementation group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '3.0.9'
```

Now the problem is that the project in which I'm using the library is also running with gradle 6.5.1 so probably this version missmatch between compiple and usage was causing the problem.
By reverting to the correct version suggested by gradle the problem is gone.